# Debugging a watchOS install from phone

Tags: swiftui, watchos, swiftui-navigationlink

I have an iOS app that I added a WatchOS to. I paired simulators, works fine. I build it for my iPhone, it runs fine. When I try to install the watch app to the watch from my phone, I get a generic error. The watch has plenty of storage. How can I see a log of why it refuses to install? [image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YThvc.jpg)

The error dialog on the watch says “This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified“

**Update**: Could it be because another developer originally made the iOS project so it has a package name for his account? `com.<hisName>...` and since I am signing with my account, I would need to change the package name to `com.<myName>.AppName` & `com.<myName>.AppName.watchkitapp`?

Comment: The name issue could be the problem. The bundles should match.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The bundle IDs matched but they needed to be for my account since I was signing it. I added my watch to my account too (UIDD). I was able to also build straight to my watch if I desired while my phone was tethered to my laptop. When I installed a new iOS app, the watch app was automatically installed for me too.